# R: ggplot: plot shows vertical lines instead of time course

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I am trying to get a simple plot showing the time course of worry duration over 6 days for two groups. However, I get vertical lines instead of a line showing the time course.

This is what my data looks like:

```
> head(alldays_dur)
            ParticipantID  Session     Day   Time    Worry_duration   group
1              1              2         1     71804      15     intervention
2              1              4         1     56095      5      intervention
3              2              2         1     36739      15     intervention
4              2              4         1     45013      10     intervention
5              2              5         1     51026      5      intervention
```

This is the structure of my data

```
> str(alldays_dur)
'data.frame':   2620 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ ParticipantID : num  113 113 113 113 113 113 113 113 113 113 ...
 $ Session       : num  9 10 11 12 14 15 16 21 22 24 ...
 $ Day           : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 
 $ Time          : num  37350 42862 47952 51555 61499 ...
 $ Worry_duration: num  5 5 5 5 10 0 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ group         : Factor w/ 2 levels "Intervention group",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(alldays_dur, aes(x=Day, y=Worry_duration, group=1)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Day", 
    y = "Mean worry duration in minutes per day")
print(p)
```

However, I get the following plot: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bkkv.png)

I have included the group=1 in the code after reading some earlier posts on this topic. However, it didn't help me as I had hoped. 
Do you maybe have some useful tips for me? Thank you in advance.

Ps. I am sorry if the post is unclear in any way, this is my first time ever posting on stackoverflow, so I am not quite familiar with all the 'post-options' yet.

Comment: try `group = group`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that before and I saw some changes but it did not get rid of the vertical lines

Comment: then it would be easier to help you if you posted some data (with `dput()`) with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The lines are just because you are joining up all the points on each day.  You may get a more informative plot if you replace `geom_line` with `geom_point`.

Comment: You have different `Session` for each unique combination `Day` and `Group`. For example, you have a `Worry_duration` of 5 and 15 for `group = "intervention"` and `Day = "1"`. Using `geom_line` will link all these points, ploting vertical lines as you can see. 

If you want only one point per `Day`, summarize your data.

Comment: Thank you @bVa, this helped me to get what I wanted

Comment: @bVa I want to accept your answer, but I do not see a checkmark in front of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to summarize your data first, with `ddply` for example:

```
require(plyr) # ddply
require(ggplot2) # ggplot

# Creating dataset
raw_data = data.frame(Day = sample(c(1:6),100, replace = T),
                  group = sample(c("group_1", "group_2"),100, replace = T),
                  Worry_duration = sample(seq(0,30,5), 100, replace = T))

# Summarize
DF = ddply(raw_data, c("Day", "group"), summarize, 
           Worry_duration.mean = mean(Worry_duration, na.rm = T))

# Plot
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Day, y = Worry_duration.mean, group = group, color = group)) +
geom_line()+ xlab("Day") + ylab("Mean worry duration in minutes per day")
```

[image]